# How to combine filters in Hbase shell?

Tags: shell, filter, command, hbase

I wanna select some rows from hbase table, how to set multifilters? It seems that `AND` doesn't work.
I have tried two ways.

```
scan 'hbase_table', { FILTER => "(RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:39$') AND SingleColumnValueFilter ('binary:family','binary:qualifier', '=', 'value')" }
```

or

```
scan 'hbase_table', {LIMIT => 10, FILTER => "(RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), RegexStringComparator.new("39$")) AND SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('family'), Bytes.toBytes('qualifier'), CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), Bytes.toBytes('value')))", COLUMNS => 'family:qualifier'}
```

many thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first command is correct. Can you try individual filters and see if they are working fine. Then try with AND. [This](http://www.hadooptpoint.com/filters-in-hbase-shell/) can help you if needed

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked long back, but just in case it helps someone...

I have tried combining prefixfilter and SingleColumnValueFilter like below and it works as expected:

```
scan 'dbtest:table1', {FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('abc') AND SingleColumnValueFilter('cf','age',>=, 'binary:10',true,false)"}
```

Here

- dbtest is my namespace, if its default for you then you can skip
- cf is my column family
- age is a column
- This should result in rows having 'abc' as prefix and 'cf:age' column value >= 10

[This link](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/thrift.html) should help understand the filters better

Answer (score 1):

Using only SingleColumnValueFilter

```
scan 'table', {FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter
    ('columnfamily', 'columnname', =, 'binary:value', true, false) 
AND SingleColumnValueFilter('columnfamily', 'columnname', =, 'binary:value', true, false)"}
```

Replace following fields,

**table** - hbase table name ex: hbaseTemp

**columnfamily** - hbase column family name ex: s

**columnname** - hbase column name ex: id

value - hbase field value ex: 12343

Docx for SingleColumnValueFilter: https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SingleColumnValueFilter.html